# Running Laravel Dusk on Homestead

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-dusk

I use Homestead **Version 1.0.1** and **Laravel version 5.4.16**. I setup the Laravel dusk by reading [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#installation).

But, when I run `php artisan dusk` by ssh to my homestead. I got an error like the following

> PHPUnit 5.7.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> E                                                                   1
>   / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 2.52 minutes, Memory: 10.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown
>   for http POST to /session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["no-first-run"]}}}
>
> Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be found on the github pages of Dusk. It is a known issue and they are working to update the next homestead box.

> The basic issue is that the homestead box has no visual interface and
>   that dusk runs a real browser, so you have to install a chromedriver
>   if you want to use it.

But for now this worked for me:
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/50#issuecomment-275155974

Not included in that post but necessary for me:
make sure you have following permission set `cd vendor/laravel/dusk/bin; chmod 775 *`

Steps from the github post:
First of all, google-chrome is requried to be installed in guest OS:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Next thing is xvfb:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
```

Try to start `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --port=8888.` If you have some errors about loading libraries (libnss3.so, libgconf-2.so.4), try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-dev libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

When you see

```
$ ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --port=8888
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e) on port 8888
Only local connections are allowed.
this means ChromeDriver can be started (so SupportsChrome trait should be able to start it too). You can stop this process for now (Ctrl+C).
```

Run

```
$ Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1280x960x24 &
in a separate terminal window.
```

Also you may want to add your dev domain in guest's /etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.1 domain.dev.

> This issue is to add the chromedriver to homestead by default and will
>   be solved mid April. https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/516

Comment: I've installed google-chrome-stable as suggested, got things to run without complaining about dependencies, started the xvfb command with your exact parameters, yet I still get the timeout error... I'm trying to run Dusk in a Debian jessie container on a macOS host. From the host OS, Dusk is able to launch a browser. The permissions of chromedriver-linux are 755 in the container.